# Can we use Metron Stellar query language in querying from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I used Stellar query language coming in metron platform to enrich the data while indexing to ElasticSearch.

I wonder if there is a way to use the same stellar query language while querying from Kibana!

Answer (score 0):

At present the kibana queries are only possible with lucence query syntax. Stellar does not at present have many search type functions but certainly could develop in that way, and could certainly form part of the strategy for a Metron native UI.